# Is it possible to wrap HTTPS communication into MQTT?

Tags: https, proxy, mqtt, vpn, gateway

again I am struggling with my lack of protocol knowledge.

**Basic situation:**

Device A wants to communicate with Device Z via HTTPS.

Device A is not connected to the internet but only to an internal network allowing MQTT only. Let's call this the "internal bus" B.
Also connected to B is an MQTT -> HTTPS Gateway G which has internet access.

**Question:**

Would it be possible to wrap the complete HTTPS traffic between A and Z into MQTT payloads and use those MQTT-Packages for as well the handshaking and the data transfer - in a way that Device A and Z are not "disturbed" in their HTTPS communication?

This does not refer to somehow decrypting packages: everything should be wrapped as is into MQTT and routed forward via G - so it would be something like an OSI layer 8.

**Evaluation:**

My gut feeling says, that it should work somehow, but I think that to actually achieve this I would have to write my own "network driver" or "network hook" on Device A and on the Gateway G

What do you think regarding feasability?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I'm not convinced this is really on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hardillb: Where would you put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is possible (Nearly anything is possible if you try hard enough, people have written whole VPNs that run over DNS lookups) I would question the return on investment.

You would need 2 topics, one for each direction of the communication and a tun/tap device on the gateway to write/read the packets to. Add in a NAT layer and it would work at the IP layer rather than at a HTTP Proxy level.

Comment: Why IP level and not transport level? 
In the end it probably doesn't matter: It seems to be really a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

If security is your concern and for some reason you cannot (or do not need to) use MQTT over TLS in the local network, You can use a reverse proxy for TLS termination at the edge of the local network. This is quite easy to do with Nginx (detailed in the article below)

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-tcp/

If for some reason you absolutely need to use HTTPS, a protocol gateway should do the trick but I wouldn't do this unless I absolutely had to.